# the use of formula inside mapply

Tags: r, list, vegan, mapply

Im trying to apply an simple formula `y~x` to a function, in this case `adonis {vegan}` when inside `mapply` but I get **Error: object of type 'symbol' is not subsettable**.

Im running: `mapply(adonis, formula=dist_list~group_list, data=group_list, SIMPLIFY=F)`, where dist_list is a list of distance matrices in dist class and group_list a list of factors. The same works with single dist and factor objects. This also works: `mapply(betadisper, d = dist_list, group = group_list, SIMPLIFY=FALSE)`.

So the problem seem to be with the use of a `formula` inside `mapply`. I've been trying the use of `substitute` but ending up with the same error.

Here's an attempt of providing a reproducible example:

```
data(varespec)

dis <- vegdist(varespec, method="bray")
dis1 <- vegdist(varespec,method="jaccard")
dis2 <- vegdist(varespec,method="mountford")

dist_list <- list(dis,dis1,dis2)

groups <- factor(c(rep(1,16), rep(2,8)), labels = c("grazed","ungrazed"))
groups1 <- factor(c(rep(1,10), rep(2,14)), labels = c("grazed","ungrazed"))
groups2 <- factor(c(rep(1,20), rep(2,4)), labels = c("grazed","ungrazed"))

group_list <- list(groups,groups1,groups2)

mapply(adonis, formula=dist_list~group_list, data=group_list, SIMPLIFY=F)

#Error: object of type 'symbol' is not subsettable
```

Any pointer to sort this out would be very much appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to work though

```
mapply(function(x,y) adonis(x~y), dist_list, group_list, SIMPLIFY=FALSE)
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the `MoreArgs` argument to pass additional arguments to `adonis` when using `mapply`.  see the `mapply` documentation.  Something like (untested):

```
mapply(
  adonis, group_list=group_list, dist_list=dist_list, 
  MoreArgs=list(formula=dist_list~group_list), 
  SIMPLIFY=F
)
```

Otherwise `mapply` is going to attempt to cycle through your formula as it were a list/vector, which is what is causing the error.

Comment: Thanks for commenting. But I get `Error in model.frame.default(formula, data, drop.unused.levels = TRUE) : 
  invalid type (list) for variable 'group_list'`